# How to read data from .adf file and insert into mysql table using php?

Tags: php

Anyone knows how to read ADF file from the URL in PHP and render it and save it in MySQL table?

When I use function like

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($_REQUEST['adfpath']) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

it's showing

> Error: Cannot create object

Below is the ADF File Sample:

```
<?ADF VERSION "1.0"?>
<?XML VERSION "1.0"?>
<adf>
     <prospect>
        <requestdate>2010-11-18</requestdate>
        <vehicle>
            <year></year>
            <make></make>
            <model></model>
        </vehicle>
        <customer>
             <contact>
                   <name part="first">Test11</name>
                   <name part="last">mctester</name>
                        <address type ="home">
                             <street line ="1">1722 W test test RD</street>
                             <city></city>
                             <state>AZ</state>
                             <postalcode></postalcode>
                        </address>
                   <phone type="voice"></phone>
              </contact>
        </customer>
        <vendor>
            <vendorname>
            Test vender
            </vendorname>
        </vendor>
        <provider>
            <name part='full'>test11 test22 </name>
            <service>Leads - </service>
            <url>test</url>
            <email>test</email>
            <phone>800-123-4567</phone>
            <contact primarycontact='1'>
            <name part='full'>Dennys Test11</name>
            <email>test</email>
            <phone type='voice' time='day'></phone>
            <phone type='fax' time='day'></phone>
            <address>
            <street line='1'>Apple </street>
            <street line='2'>K Mart </street>
            <city></city>
            <regioncode></regioncode>
            <postalcode></postalcode>
            <country>US</country>
            </address>
            </contact>
        </provider>
     </prospect>
</adf>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: It looks like it's still XML at the heart of it, no?

Comment: Anyways, you might find this helpful - http://www.codethattalks.com/a-quick-php-based-adf-xml-example/

Comment: I know this is old but what was the solution? The link above is dead and I am needing to do something similar with simplexml. Thanks!